# Understanding contradictions found in VB's official conventions guidelines

Tags: vb.net, winforms, naming-conventions, naming, convention

I was hoping fellow members could assist me in making sense of the following six contradictory guidelines:

## a) Name Length:

Advises abbreviation...

> For long [...] terms, use abbreviations to keep name lengths
>   reasonable.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx,)

Advises against abbreviation:

> DO NOT use abbreviations or contractions as part of identifier names.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx,)

Which is it? To contract or not to contract? PromotionalNumberTextBox or PromNumTextBox?

## <s>b) Event Handler names:</s>

> Begin event handler names with a noun describing the type of event
>   followed by the "EventHandler" suffix, as in "MouseEventHandler".

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx,)

<s>Thia doesn't correspond with what Visual Studio automatically generates. See `Button1_Click` event handler below that follows the format of control, underscore and event.</s>

**Edit:** Not, in fact, a contradiction. See comment by jmcilhinney for explanation.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '... 
End Sub
```

## c) Hungarian Notation:

> DO NOT use Hungarian notation.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx,)

...and yet both of the following seem like a variant of Hungarian Notation.

> Objects should be named with a consistent prefix that makes
>   it easy to identify the type of object. [...] chkReadOnly [...]
>   lblHelpMessage

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263493%28v=vs.60%29.aspx,)

> Use [...] prefixes to indicate a variable's data type. [...]
>   intQuantity

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240858%28v=vs.60%29.aspx,)

## d) Acronyms Capitalization:

> For long [...] terms, use abbreviations [...] for example, "HTML",
>   instead of "Hypertext Markup Language".

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx,)

> [...] PascalCasing [...] for [...] acronyms over two letters in length
>   [...] examples: [...] HtmlTag".

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx,)

This is ambiguous. Let's say I have the acronym PIN. Should it be PINTextBox or PinTextBox?

## e) Comments:

> Put comments on a separate line instead of at the end of a line of
>   code.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx,)

> Comments can follow a statement on the same line, or occupy an entire
>   line.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx185bk6.aspx,)

This is ambiguous. Are inline comments recommended or not?

## f) Asterisk Line Separators:

> Do not surround comments with formatted blocks of asterisks.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx,)
However, the following example using formatted blocks asterisks is also provided:

```
'*****************************************************
' Purpose:   Locates the first occurrence of a
'            specified user in the UserList array.
' Inputs:
'   strUserList():   the list of users to be searched.
'   strTargetUser:   the name of the user to search for.
' Returns:   The index of the first occurrence of the
'            rsTargetUser in the rasUserList array.
'            If target user is not found, return -1.
'*****************************************************
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733583%28v=vs.60%29.aspx,)

Comment: I do controls diff than variables, they have a 2/3 letter prefix, tbFirstname - textbox, cbSave - Checkbox, this way I can find my textboxes by the typing 2 letters and intellisence gives me all the textboxes to choose from. Variable are made to make sense - what does it do or store - no prefix. You will have to figure out what you want or what your employer wants.

Comment: @OneFineDay Thanks for sharing your convention on controls and variables. At this stage, I'm trying to base what I want on what Microsoft wants (presuming I can eventually find consistency in their recommendations).

Comment: Visual Basic has been around for a very, very long time.  Those naming conventions came from the previous century.  Trying to reconcile them with modern conventions is of course going to be difficult.  There is little reason to maintain the Visual Basic style unless you work in a team that has been around for a long time and has stuck to traditional conventions.  Trying to convince members of such a team that they've been doing it wrong all this time isn't going to work btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the context. It's just frustrating not having a regimented standard to adhere to. Invariably, one practice should be better than other no matter how nominal the disparity may be. It's furthermore antagonizing that Microsoft is providing conflicting guidelines. It's now clear to me that I need to wing it at my own discretion, like everyone else seems to be doing.

Comment: I'm still open to a few subjective opinions on whether contraction vs English-readability is deemed superior.

Comment: Your section B is irrelevant.  The specified convention is talking about the delegates that represent an event, not the methods used to handle those events.  For instance, the `Control.MouseDown` event is type `MouseEventHandler`, just as the documentation suggests, but you'd still use a method named `MyControl_MouseDown` to handle that event for a specific control.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Understood. Thanks for the clarification. Contradiction B stroked out and edit appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I advise:

#### Name length

From a "clean code" perspective, variable names should be [intention revealing](http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83). I want a variable's purpose to be clear to whoever reads my code, so go for a descriptive name as opposed to using abbreviations which the reader might be unaware of.

#### Event Handler Names

As you're using the Visual Basic framework for generating event handler names, I'd work with Visual Basic's convention.

However, instead of opting to use the default event handler name that gets generated you should, as the general naming conventions recommend, add more information to the method name so the reader knows exactly what it does e.g. instead of "Button1_Click" use "SaveButton_Click" for example.

#### Hungarian Notation

[Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is generally not required as it is easy to view the variable type by inspecting it in a modern IDE e.g. ItemCount would be better that intItemCount; adding an abbreviated descriptor just adds "noise".

However, a variable name should still be intention revealing, so instead of grdPrices (for example) I'd use PricesGrid. The benefit of this approach means that the code can also be understood by all i.e. they won't need to know the meaning of the VB prefix abbreviations.

#### Acronyms Capitalization

Acronyms should be capitalised.

Using this convention a reader will instantly know that a word all in caps is an acronym. For example in your scenario if you use "PinTextBox", do you mean a text box for a small slender piece of metal used to support, fasten or attach things, or a Personal Identification Number (i.e. PIN)?

#### Comments

Well written code should be self-documenting, so comments should be unnecessary. *However* comments are recommended if you need to document why an esoteric/non-obvious piece of code has been used.

When you have to add a comment, placing it on its own line above the code works well, as a reader has to read the comment first before they encounter the code you want to highlight.

#### Asterisk Line Separators

If the VB framework automatically generates file headers with asterisks, then you could just work with that. However comment blocks without asterisks work better as in practice you find that sometimes there's so much text, the comment flows outside the asterisks. It looks far neater if the asterisks are removed.

Comment: **c)** In lieu of the Hungarian method, what alternative are you recommending? In the context of a text box and a corresponding label for, let's say, password input, how would you infer distinction between the two names and not use a variant of the Hungarian Method (prefixes/suffixes) since no two objects can share the one name? Furthermore, should your answer be control-identifying prefixes/suffixes e.g. `PasswordTextBox`, would you consistently impose this on controls not requiring distinction from labels? e.g. Would you name your button `LogInButton` or `LogIn`?

Comment: @ClarusDignus I've updated my answer regarding Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 0):

A *workable* convention would be when one or another understand each word of your code on the fly. Especially your colleagues or depending on the requirements of your employer.

---

**a) Long names.**

Is it easy to read longnames ? No ! Find the most explicit meaning using the fewest characters.
Or use another approach of coding : Object.Property/divide your method in several ones

```
Sub ReturnLeftCup_SwapWithNext_ReturnEveryCups(...)
    ' ...

' Prefer
Sub ManipulateCups(...)
    ReturnLeftCup(...)
    SwapCupWithNext(...)
    ReturnAllCups(...)
End Sub
```

---

**b) EvenHandler suffix.**

My understanding is *that's not contradictory* :

- Write the event handler name/signification/action : `ButtonClick` or `Button_Click`
- Dont write "EventHandler" : `ButtonClickEventHandler` or `ButtonClick_EventHandler`

The string "EventHandler" was automaticaly appended to the method handling the event in the VB6 IDE even if the event name (Click/Enter) was clearly appended aswell.

---

**c) Hungarian Notation :**

To find every TextBox in your entire solution, it would be easy to look for texts like with the search tool or intellisense :

- "TextBox_"
- "TBox_"
- "TBX_"
- ...

If you ommit the prefix, I'll have to list the name of any TBox then search for them one by one...

By the way, if you have a Label, a TextBox and a Button related to a Custommer validation form.

```
Private Sub ClickCustommer(...) Handles bCustommer.Click
    lCustommer.Text = tCustommer.Text.ToUpper()
End Sub
' :/ bCustommer is a Button obviously.
' but are lCustommer and/or tCustommer controls or objects ?

Private Sub Button_Custommer_Click(...) Handles ButtonCustommer.Click
    Label_Custommer.Text = TextBox_Custommer.Text.ToUpper()
End Sub
' better don't you think ?
```

Use prefixes for controls, and no prefixes for variables/objects (that are not controls)

***Prefixes (like `TextB_User`) or suffixes (like `User_TextB`) ?***

**Caution ! Personal opinion** :

Used prefixes long ago. Then changed my mind... Then changed my mind again :/

If you use suffixes, the controls of your Form are not ordered by type in the control list DropdownList of the IDE. When you forgot you've put buttons inside panels inside tabpages inside splittercontainer inside .... all docked to fill container client space, good luck finding a Panel of alike.
But if you used prefixes, TextBox_Custommer, Label_Custommer, Panel_Custommer ... all those controls related to the same context are messed up in that DropdownList.

I've chosen the ease of retrieving a Panel nested in another one (only the topmost panel could be selected in the Form Preview) so I'm stick with prefixes.

A good addition to (some) IDEs would be a Component Name filtering next to the DropdownList.

---

**d) Acronyms Capitalization**

*PINTextBox or PinTextBox ?*

Both could be correct for me if I can understand elsewhere in your code what is "PIN" or "Pin". The problem is not in the name of the TextBox, it's the context : Do I have a clear picture of the usage of this TextBox or do I have to guess what PIN or Pin is ?

If I have to guess :

- PINTextBox -> "PIN" seems to be an acronym, but I don't know its meaning. "Poor Identifier Name" ?
- PinTextBox -> Pin what ?

For "HtmlTag", it's easier to read than "HTMLTag" and shorter than "HTML_Tag".

---

**e) Comments:**

Inline comments are good when they fits in the IDE. I hate to scroll to the right to read a comment. What about you ? However, I hate to ask myself if a comment belongs to the code above or below. What about you ?

=> Inline comments are neither good or bad. A comment is a good one when it add something usefull using the fewest words without adding noise in the workflow (reading the code)

---

**f) Asterisk Line Separators:**

They were a must when you couldn't organize your code in blocks. Today, you have :

```
Public Partial Class MyMultipleFilesClass
```

---

```
#Region "UserInterface Section"
Private Sub ChangeFormBackground(...)
Private Sub ResizeIconPictureB(...)
' ...
#End Region
```

---

```
[+] Private Function OutputLeftWord(...) As String
[+] Private Function FixWordCasing(...) As String
[-] Private Sub ExtractWords(...)
        Dim CurrentWord As String
        While ...
            CurrentWord = FixWordCasing(OutputLeftWord(...))
            ...
        End While
    End Function
[+] Private Sub FormatRTF()
```

---

You can create Objects instead of putting everything in `Module`

etc.

---

You asked for subjective opinion ? (in comment)

**I'm french-speaking to begin with**. Programming language and IDE languages standards is English. You were seeking for standardization, this is the first to adopt.

I don't write variables/functions/methods/etc. in French. (I often see variables names in German. It's fine as long as I can figure out the meaning **by looking at the code**. Otherwise, I don't bother using a translator, and go on or have a cup of tea.)

Not really related to Contraction vs Readability, but somewhat the same issue : **"is it clear or not in a single shot ?"**

If you're afraid the contraction ends unintelligible, use either comments, or XML Doc :

```
''' <summary>
''' Scalar that defines the amount of available power
''' of the Character in this (fight) game.
''' <para>Used to draw Power Level Bar Indicator on top of Screen<para>
''' <para>Used to compute damage bonus upon hit.<para>
''' <para>Used to compute shield strength.<para>
''' </summary>
Private p_CharacterPower As Integer
```

^^ I won't have to right click the variable, then "Goto definition" to read a comment next to the declaration each time I forgot about its meaning.

For the other bits, I've explained above *what I assume that might be the general consensus* : identifiers full of meaning in english.

But it's up to you. You can't control how others will judge your coding standards and you can't force others to comform to yours.

Comment: **a)** I've very recently rewrote some of my methods adopting this very approach. It's great to read confirmation that I'm on the right track. **b)** Noted. Question edited. **c)** Concurred. **d)** [Personal Identification Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number) **e)** Since my code lines are constrained to 80 characters I'll opt for comments on top... _consistently_. :-). **f** This contradiction pertains to comments exclusively rather than "non-comment" code sections so I don't think regions apply.

Comment: @ClarusDignus - Thanks for PIN (**d)**). Sorry, I somewhat guessed, but I know some french (friends) wouldn't. Sorry for **b)** but I was pretty sure (and still) in the old days of the last century, double clicking a button in the VB6 IDE generating the event handling method would append that annoying "EventHandler" suffix to the method name (very loooong method names) - but jmcilhinney is right. **f)** Correct. You can't use #Region inside a method/function :) I rarely use multiline comments. I mix XML Doc with methods splitted in sub methods to keep track on what's going on (**a)** + XMLDoc)